# Display variable from link into input value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have this link to an image inside `td` table:

```
....   
echo "</tr><tr>";
for ($i=0; $i<count($prov_name);$i++) {

echo "<td><a onclick='showDiv()' ><img src='images/approved.png'/></a></td>";
}
     }
        echo "</tbody>";                  
        echo "\t</table>\n";
        echo "</div>";
?>
```

and then I have a hide `div` that appears when I clicked the link above.

```
<div id="approve" style="height: 300px;">
<input type="text" name="ProvSelected" value="" readonly>
....
```

and what I want is when I click the link image pass the variable `$prov_name[$i]` to the input value inside the `div` that appears.

How can I do that? I hope you can help me. Thanks.

First Click
[image]

then.. with variable inside input value..
[image]

Comment: Send with ShowDiv($prov_name[$]) and inside this function you can set value for input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rewrite the code like this:

Remove the `<a>` tag...you don't need it

Rewrite `<img>` with onclick added:

```
echo "<td><img src='images/approved.png' onclick='showDiv(\"".$prov_name[$i]."\")'/></td>";
```

Add an ID for the input

```
<input id="myInput" name="ProvSelected" value="" readonly>
```

Update the function `showDiv()`

```
function showDiv(val) {
  //your code plus
  document.getElementById("myInput").value = val;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass the prov name as an argument to `showDiv()`.

```
foreach ($prov_name as $prov) {
    echo "<td><a onclick='showDiv(\"$prov\")' ><img src='images/approved.png'/></a></td>";
}
```

Then `showDiv` should be defined as something like:

```
function showDiv(prov) {
    $("#approve").show().find("input[name=ProvSelected]").val(prov);
}
```

Comment: Works if I don't change the `for` and obvisly using `$prov_name[$i]` instead $prov.
Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: Yeah, that works too. I was just showing the easier way to do it. Why use `for` when `foreach` is simpler?